# What is the difference between "darse vuelta" and "darse la vuelta"?

Tags: expresiones, significado

I was wondering what does "la" change and if one of these forms is incorrect or more commonly used. And also, could you give me their definitions?

Answer (score 3):

I had never heard *darse vuelta* (without the article), but I assume it's the American variation of *darse la vuelta* (Spain). It has more occurrences [on Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=darse%20la%20vuelta%2C%20darse%20vuelta&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdarse%20la%20vuelta%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdarse%20vuelta%3B%2Cc0) (not surprising, as American speakers are many more than European Spanish).

For the examples I've checked on Google, I would say the meaning is the same.

Comment: We use "darse vuelta" for "turn (a)round", and "dar la vuelta" for "turn the corner". We never say "darse la vuelta".

Comment: @Gustavson - When you have time, I suggest you make an answer out of that.

Comment: Wait so what is correct? "Darse vuelta" or "darse la vuelta"? And isn't "dar vuelta" and "dar la vuelta" the same thing as "darse vuelta" and "darse la vuelta"? Don't they mean to turn around? And these forms are never conjugated right?

Comment: I am now confused on what to trust.

Comment: I've never heard or used "darse la vuelta". To me, it is either wrong or some regional use.

Answer (score 3):

In his “Diccionario de dudas y dificultades de la lengua española”, Manuel Seco says, in reference to the expression “dar vuelta”:

> *Dar vuelta*, locución verbal transitiva, ‘volver’, usada en varias zonas de América, al menos en la del Río de la Plata y Chile (Kany, 2). Esta locución tiene la particularidad de que en ella *vuelta*, a pesar de la apariencia, no es complemento directo, sino componente fijo, a manera de formante, de la locución, la cual funciona como una unidad verbal transitiva, es decir, con su complemento directo propio: “*Por más que demos vuelta los papeles..., no vamos a encontrar plata*” (Bioy, *Cavar*); “*Maya retrocede un paso. Luego da vuelta la espalda y desaparece*” (Donoso, *Domingo*); “*Se daba vuelta las mangas del saco, de la camisa*” (Mallea, *Cuentos*). El complemento directo puede ser reflexivo: “*Tartamudeó Casiano con una vos tan débil y lejana que Chaparro **se dio vuelta** creyendo que le hablaba otro*” (Roa, *Hijo*). La locución, al ser transitiva, puede aparecer en construcción pasiva: “*Nuestros conceptos serán dados vuelta*” (Candioti, cit. Kany).

In short, the expression “dar vuelta” is used mostly in Latin America to mean “turn”, and so is its reflexive variant, “darse vuelta”, for a person turning around.

Locally, we use “dar **la** vuelta” to mean “turn the corner” (we can also say “dar vuelta la esquina” to express the same concept).

“darse **la** vuelta” seems to be mostly used only in Spain.

To mean "go for a walk", in Latin America we use both "dar una vuelta" and "darse una vuelta":

- Voy a dar una vuelta / Voy a dar una vuelta por el parque.
- **Me** voy a dar una vuelta / **Me** voy a dar una vuelta por el parque / Voy a dar**me** una vuelta por el parque.

Comment: I'll just retain the most common form "dar la vuelta." "Dar la vuelta" normally means to turn around or to avoid right?

Answer (score 0):

"Darse una vuelta" (I have never heard this expression without the article) means "to go for a walk", while "darse la vuelta" means "to turn around".