# When do you use pronouns with the phrase "dar vuelta"?

Tags: gramática

At first I thought that these were just reflexive pronouns. But now, i'm just confused.

> no te des la vuelta. (This sentence has the pronoun "te")
>
> No des vuelta, ¿okey? Tu ex está justo detrás de nosotros en la fila. (This sentence doesn't)

More example:

> doy vuelta a la izquierda I turn to the left.
>
> ¿Doy vuelta a la derecha?
>
> Grité el nombre de mi amiga varias veces, pero no se dio vuelta.
>
> Da vuelta a la derecha.
>
> El bandido se dio la vuelta y le disparó al comisario.
>
> Por favor dale vuelta a la hoja y contesta el cuestionario.
>
> Debes darle vuelta a tu colchón para que se usen los dos lados.

Additional question:
Why do some sentences have "la vuelta" as if it is a noun and others are just "vuelta"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "darse vuelta" and "darse la vuelta"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23906/what-is-the-difference-between-darse-vuelta-and-darse-la-vuelta) "Dar vuelta" appears to be more common in Latin America, whereas "darse la vuelta" is typically used in Spain.

Comment: It does but when you say "Dar vuelta", you mean "Dar vuelta" as well as its reflexive variant "Darse vuelta" like the link suggested right? If not, I´m lost again.

Comment: Good point. Maybe I shouldn't have been so eager to vote to close as a duplicate. Your example _Grité el nombre de mi amiga varias veces, pero no se dio vuelta._ uses "darse vuelta", while most of your other examples use "dar vuelta" or "darse la vuelta". I'm pretty sure both "darse vuelta" and "darse vuelta" are both used in American Spanish (no idea whether both of them are used everywhere in Latin America with the same meaning, though). In European Spanish, we always say "**la** vuelta".

Comment: In European Spanish, we tend to say "darse la vuelta" (or, in general, "dar la vuelta [a algo]" when we are talking about turning in place (for instance, your second example would be _No te des la vuelta, ¿vale? Tu ex está justo detrás de nosotros en la fila_ in European Spanish. Your last example would be _Debes darle la vuelta a tu colchón para que se usen los dos lados_). When talking about reversing your direction of movement, it's just "dar la vuelta" ("Da la vuelta en la rotonda"). However, we wouldn't say "Doy la vuelta a la izquierda", but "Giro a la izquierda" or something like that.